# C++ library as submodule not found by linker

Tags: ros2, colcon, library, submodule

I added a CMake-based library as a submodule of a package of mine.

With `colcon` I can correctly build and install the library file and the include files in the `install` folder of my workspace.

My problem is that the linker cannot find the library when building my package.

I know it's a problem of path, but I have not understood how to correctly set the path to find it.

Thank you in advance
Walter

Comment: Do you have the library as a subdirectory in one of your ROS 2 packages?

Comment: Exactly, I created that library, but I do not want to make it a "ROS library" to make it free to use for other purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this before, and indeed we need to be careful with linking. I will assume that, for example, we have a ROS 2 package that uses a third-party  C++ library called ***libcustom*** that is included in the package as a subdirectory. This third-party library needs to be compiled with our package. Then, in the package's CMakeLists.txt, we should add the following line.

```
add_subdirectory(libcustom)
```

Notice that the third-party library must have its own CMakeLists.txt file, which CMake will process during the build configuration. This subdirectory is named `libcustom` in the previous command.

Let's see **how to link** our targets (executables or libraries) against this library. It is done as follows.

```
target_link_libraries(executable_name libcustom)
```

**Why would we use `target_link_libraries` instead of `ament_target_dependencies`?**

The command `ament_target_dependencies` is specific to the ROS 2 build system, provided by the ament_cmake package. It is used to specify that a target depends on certain ROS 2 packages or libraries. When we use `ament_target_dependencies`, it automatically handles include directories, and compilation and linking dependencies. It ensures all necessary components are properly included and linked.

However, in our case, when using a third-party library, we need to link explicitly with `target_link_libraries.` This standard CMake command links a target against any library (not necessarily ROS 2 packages), including system libraries and third-party libraries.

**How to be sure about the library name in the command `target_link_libraries`?**

This is the last piece we need to get right. It is simple. Look into the third-party library's CMakeLists.txt file for the command `add_library`, which defines the library as its first argument.

I hope this helps. Feel free to let me know if you need more help with that.

Comment: `add_subdirectory(libcustom)` solved the issue. Thank you